# Should I increment or decrement the reverse iterator?

Tags: c++, algorithm, reverse-iterator

As given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/188959/), a good way to iterate backwards through a list is to use `rbegin()`, as below:

```cpp
list<DVFGfxObj*>::reverse_iterator iter = m_Objs.rbegin();
for( ; iter != m_Objs.rend(); ++iter) {
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot remember whether to `++iter` or `--iter`.  Because we are going backwards, using `--iter`, too, seems logical to me.

I am seeking an intuitive explanation so that I can remember it forever.  I do not wish to look it up *every single time*.

Comment: Think of doing steps you count. `r` or not indicates the direction taken.

Comment: You want to use ++ here. In reverse iterators, ++ will also work in reverse.

Comment: General rule of thumb, you increment from begin to end, you decrement from end to begin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *only reason* to have a reverse iterator is to go backwards through the sequence.  If you were OK with using `--` you could just use a regular iterator.  Always use `++`.